# NoneType object is not callable when trying to save instance of Model

Tags: django, object, model, save

I am using Django to perform a very simple function. The application will grow in size as time goes on, but for now, all I want to do is run through an html document of all my Facebook messages, and save a model for every user, and every message attached to that user. However when trying to create an instance of a model I created, FacebookUser, I get the error "NoneType" object is not callable. I read other SO articles, and browsed the internet for other issues, and found that the error usually stemmed from trying to do something with the class itself, and not an instantiation of the class. However I am creating an instance of this class, and still getting this error.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class FacebookUser(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(FacebookUser)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)
    date_sent = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '#{} {}'.format(self.id, self.user.full_name)
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from facebook_user.models import FacebookUser, Message
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def crawl_messages(request):
    data = open('messages.html', 'r').read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

    all_messages = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "message"})
    msg_dictionaries = [{
                            'user': el.findAll('span')[0],
                            'time': el.findAll('span')[1],
                            'content': el.nextSibling.nextSibling
                        } for el in all_messages]

    for msg in msg_dictionaries:
        try:
            fbuser = FacebookUser.objects.get(full_name=msg['user'])
            print('Try One')
            print(fbuser)
        except FacebookUser.DoesNotExist:
            fbuser = FacebookUser.objects.create(full_name=msg['user'])
            print('Try Two')
            print(fbuser)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Try Three')
            print(e)
            fbuser = None

        if fbuser:
            new_msg = Message()

            new_msg.content = msg['content']
            new_msg.user = fbuser
            new_msg.save()

    return HttpResponse('Worked ! Check the Admin')
```

Stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/timothybaney/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/timothybaney/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/timothybaney/Data Science/facebook_sentiment_analysis/facebook_user/views.py", line 19, in crawl_messages
    fbuser = FacebookUser.objects.create(full_name=msg['user'])
  File "/Users/timothybaney/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/timothybaney/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 401, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/Users/timothybaney/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 708, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Users/timothybaney/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 736, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/Users/timothybaney/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 820, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/Users/timothybaney/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 859, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Users/timothybaney/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/timothybaney/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1039, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Users/timothybaney/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1059, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/Users/timothybaney/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1019, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/Users/timothybaney/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1019, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/Users/timothybaney/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1018, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "/Users/timothybaney/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 946, in prepare_value
    value = value.resolve_expression(self.query, allow_joins=False, for_save=True)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: post your stacktrace

Comment: Stack trace has been added.

Comment: this looks like a non-code issue. did you migrate your database?

Comment: your error is in this line  fbuser = FacebookUser.objects.create(full_name=msg['user']) try to print the full_name and check whether any name is getting passed of not? or try to print(msg) to see how the key value are coming

Comment: Did you check whether `msg_dictionaries` are actually a list of dictionaries?? It seems otherwise.

Comment: Your issue in `crawl_messages` function. You are not showing us correct views.py file because it should be `facebook_user/views.py`

Comment: @Mr. Nun, yes I have migrated my database. If I create a FacebookUser object in the python shell it works. Also I did a print to see if msg['user'] existed, and it does. Also msg_dictionaries is in fact a list, I sliced it to only a few object so the console isn't littered with tracebacks, but they all show up.

Comment: @Sardorbek Imomaliev,  sorry since I posted this view function, I changed the name of it. I will fix it.

Comment: check value of `msg['user']` if it is None.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This most likely means that `msg['user']` is not a string, but an object that sets any attribute when that attribute is called. And thus it receives `resolve_expression` attribute that causes above error.

For a fix, try casting `msg['user']` to a string in your create statement: 
`fbuser = FacebookUser.objects.create(str(msg['user'])`

This is just a guess, without full source to run it there's no way to be certain.